# I would like to obtain an ARRAY of matrices like the one shown here

Tags: r, arrays, list, algorithm, function

I would like to generate an array of data matrices, where each matrix will refer to a different scenario, for the purpose of example I have included only 1

```
p13=0.493;p43=0.325;p25=0.335;p35=0.574;p12=0.868
std_e2=sqrt(1-p12^2);std_e2
std_e3=sqrt(1-(p13^2+p43^2));std_e3
std_e5=sqrt(1-(p25^2+p35^2+2*p25*p35*(p13*p12)));std_e5
scenario_1<-matrix(c(3,0,0,0,0),ncol = 5,nrow = 1);scenario_1

genereting_fuction<- function(n,scenario){ 
  sample <- vector("list") 
  for (i in scenario){
    x1=rnorm(n)+scenario[i,1]
    x4=rnorm(n)+scenario[i,4]
    x2=x1*p12+std_e2*rnorm(n)+scenario[i,2]
    x3=x1*p13+x4*p43+std_e3*rnorm(n)+scenario[i,3]
    x5=x2*p25+x3*p35+std_e5*rnorm(n)+scenario[i,5]
    sample[[i]]=cbind(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
    colnames(sample[[i]])<-c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5")
  }
  sample
} 
array_scenari<-array(dim=c(5,5,2));array_scenari

for(j in 1:nrow(scenario_1)){
  set.seed(1234)
  dati_prova<- sapply(rep(1,5), function(x) genereting_fuction(x,scenario_1),simplify = 'array');dati_prova
  dati_prova<-do.call(rbind.data.frame, dati_prova);dati_prova<-as.matrix(dati_prova);dati_prova
  dati_prova<-as.matrix(dati_prova)
  array_scenari[,,j]<-dati_prova[]
}
```

I can't understand why it doesn't work and gives me an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give a concrete answer without a working reproducible example, since your function contains externally defined variables. However, the source of the error is clear. When you create an empty array with `array()` it has a single fixed dimension:

```r
matrix_classification <- array()

dim(matrix_classification)
#> [1] 1
```

And if you try to write into its third dimension you get an error:

```r
k <- 1

matrix_classification[, , k] <- "x"
#> Error in matrix_classification[, , k] <- "x": incorrect number of subscripts
```

If you want to write into an array you should define its dimensions first. For example, the following creates an empty 5 x 5 x 5 array:

```r
matrix_classification <- array("", dim = c(5, 5, 5))

dim(matrix_classification)
#> [1] 5 5 5
```

And if we want to write a matrix into the *kth* slice we can do:

```
matrix_classification[, , k] <- matrix(sample(letters, 25), nrow = 5)

matrix_classification[,,1]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,] "a"  "d"  "k"  "t"  "c" 
#> [2,] "f"  "b"  "n"  "m"  "s" 
#> [3,] "u"  "q"  "y"  "o"  "j" 
#> [4,] "l"  "g"  "h"  "w"  "v" 
#> [5,] "r"  "i"  "e"  "p"  "z"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: There is no such thing as "matrix array" - an array is just a vector with a `dim` attribute, but a 3 dimensional array can be treated as a stack of matrices, which is what you seem to be looking for. See my update.

Comment: Thank you very much, I made the change and I don't get that error anymore but I get an empty array, if I run the code for a single case without any for loop I get the array correctly. If I use the function no.

Comment: Do you have any advice ?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the other variables that aren't defined here, but make sure `nrow(scenario_1)` isn't 0. Also, in your loop it should probably be `for(k in 1:nrow(scenario_1))`

Comment: I have updated the question, you can run this code. 
I purposely defined a three-dimensional array with two matrices instead of one as the function produces it for if you enter the values correctly.
Unfortunately it does not insert them

Comment: I have to create this "support" array because within the same loop I have to make other calculations on that matrix. If I do not build this matrix, the loop will not overwrite my observations but will add them to the queue.

Comment: I also noticed that the loop for scenarios doesn't work well. Because it replicates the analogous matrix for the number of rows in the scenario without considering the real internal values

Comment: @MariannaFilippelli you've now got `for(i in scenario)`, inside your function, which should probably be `for(i in 1:nrow(scenario))`. You need to think out carefully what `i` is supposed to represent inside your loop. You've also got `genereting_fuction_fault` inside the `sapply` in your bottom loop, which is a function that doesn't exist in the example. The result I get when I correct these errors is exactly the result I expect from the code.

Comment: I need the sapply function to obtain unit samples because otherwise I lack randomness in the generation of data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242696/discussion-between-marianna-filippelli-and-allan-cameron).

Comment: @MariannaFilippelli I feel like I answered your original question, and you are trying to get me to debug the rest of your function in the comments, which is difficult and rarely works out. Perhaps you should ask a new question and create a minimal example that demonstrates your current problem.